# linux command to replace path name in a file by searching with /tmp or /home or tmpfs

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace as below in a file via `sed` or any Linux command

```
/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2"
```

with below one

```
/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2"
```

and

```
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2
```

with

```
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Comment: to be clear  when we see this entry in a file  i want to seach with /tmp and replace it with line   "/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2"

Answer (score 0):

use the below command,

```
sed -i "s|.*/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2.*|/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2|" filename
```

This command will finds for the particular sentence "/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2" with "/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2"

```
sed -i "s|.*tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2.*|tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0|" filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding it,  my actul requirment is

Comment: Did you tried using this command?

Comment: Hi Nandu, sorry for late response, yes i tried it works perfectly, thanks alot

Comment: That's cool. you can use this command in many way.